# click does not worked on the appended html

Tags: jquery, html

I have appended the new html.
but the same event does not apply on the new appended html

```
<div class="contents" id="contents">
                    <c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList }" varStatus="status">

                        <ul class="shList" id="">
                            <li class="fl">
                                <ul class="top">
                                    <li>${result.appSn}</li>
                                    <li>${result.mkType }</li>
                                    <li>${result.clasType }</li>
                                    <li>${result.appUseGrade }</li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="bottom">
                                    <p class="fl">- ${result.appNm}</p>
                                    <span class="fr">${result.inptDt}</span>
                                </div> <!--                             <th>앱번호</th> --> <%--                           <td><form:input path="MobileDetailCommand.amtAppCollInfoVO.appSn" readonly="true" /></td> --%>



                            </li>
                            <li class="fr"><img src="${result.appLeaderImg}" alt="" width="60" height="60" /></li>
                        </ul>

                    </c:forEach>


                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center">
```

and here is my javascript code which appended the new  html

```
            html+="<ul class='shList' id=''>";//1
            html+="<li class='fl'>";//2



            html+="<ul class='top'>";//ultop
            html+="<li>" +result.appSn + "</li>";
            html+="<li>" +result.mkType + "</li>";
            html+="<li>" + result.clasType + "</li>";
            html+="<li>" +result.appUseGrade + "</li>";
            html+="</ul>"//ultop


            html+="<div class = 'bottom'>";
            html+="<p class='fl'>"+result.appNm +"</p>";
            html+="<span class='fr'>"+result.inptDt +"</span>";
            html+="</div>"








            html+="</li>";//<li class='fl'>
            //html+="   <li class='fr'><img src='"+result.appLeaderImg+"'alt='' width='60' height='60' /></li>";
            html+="</ul>";//<ul class='shList' id='shList'>

            $("#contents").append(html);
```

and the event

```
$(".shList li.fl").on('click',function() {
    // window.location.replace("screenSave.do");
    console.log("clieckeddd");


    $(this).find(".sliding").toggle();

});
```

event is work fine on the old  one
but new appended html does not work

event is work fine on the old  one
but new appended html does not work

event is work fine on the old  one
but new appended html does not work

Comment: try with `$(document).on('click', ".shList li.fl",function()`

Answer (score 0):

The click() binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using on().

Change your click event as below.

```
$(document).on('click', ".shList li.fl",function() {
    console.log("clieckeddd");
    //$(this).find(".sliding").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Looks very much as a copy of my answer, second, you should also add and explanation why this is needed.